# Usage of the modal verb "will" in context

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

I came across rather strange for me the usage of "will". Here goes: " Loads of things has happened to me today. It will seem strange." Did the speaker use "will" as an intesifier to mean the things happened to him is annoying?

Comment: Is that an exact quote?  It is unusual for native speakers to say "Loads of things *has* happened" rather than the correct "*have*".  Is the quote from a native speaker?  If it is, I'd say that "It will seem strange" probably means "It will seem to strange [to you] [when you hear what happened]", i.e. you'll be surprised by the events that he or she is about to recount to you.

Comment: more context please. As it stands the first sentence is not grammatical. The second is a non-sequitur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this person was about to tell you the strange things that have happened to him/her, then it makes sense. With the second sentence, the person is basically saying to you:

> The things that have happened to me will seem strange to you.

Sometimes people say something like this before they tell a thrilling story to a friend:

> Sit down, get ready, this is going to sound strange/wild/crazy.

Other similar and fun sentences include:

> Hold onto your horses, you are not going to believe this!
>
> Hold on to your hat, this is going to blow your mind!

Future tense is not used as an intensifier, as far as I know.